# How do I secure a subdomain using UCC SSL?

Tags: plugins, media, subdomains, ssl, https

I have a UCC SSL Certificate installed on my primary domain (example.com). I have 3 subdomains listed as Subject Alternative Names (SANs) (shop.example.com, distributors.example.com and careers.example.com).

Currently, I'm working on the shop subdomain. I installed the Wordpress HTTPS (SSL) plugin, but when I try to go to say, (link 1) https://shop.example.com, it redirects to (link 2) https://example.com.

I cannot for the life of me figure it out. I tried changing the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) in General Settings to https instead of http and at least it didn't redirect me to login to the example.com, but directly typing in (link 1) still directed me to (link 2). Also, that created another problem.....none of my media would show. I have "Googled" for days and cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The UCC SSL Certificate is used to secure multiple domains like www.example.com, www. example.net, www.example.co.uk etc. and if you want to secure your subdomains like shop.example.com, distributors.example.com and careers.example.com then you should try **Unified Communication Wildcard Certificate** instead of UCC SSL Certificate because it protects both multi-domains as well as subdomains.

Comment: UC (or SAN) SSL certs can include multiple domains **and** sub-domains, either all under the same domain like hkcweb's example.com, shop.example.com, etc, or using different domains like example.com, www.example2.com, mail.example3.net, etc; however, the number of domains/sub-domains you can add is limited. A Wildcard SSL certificate secures a single domain and all of it's first-level subdomains, *.example.com.